# Grails won't load changes done in static resources (except when restarting)

Tags: caching, grails

I have an annoying problem with my new grails app. I'm trying to mock up a design for a site that I will be making but whenever I do changes in my css it won't affect the running application. No matter how big changes I do I have to stop the application and then run it again.

This is very frustrating, I've turned of cache in Chrome and even if I go to the specific document the resource is still the old. What can I do to solve this problem? I can make changes in my `gsp` files and the changes will appear but not in my css.

I am currently loading the resource within a layout file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'app.css')}" type="text/css">
```

If you need me to provide any more information, please just ask. I am using grails 2.2.0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your Config.groovy (probably just for development)

```
grails.resources.debug = true
```

Read the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, I were looking for it but could not really find it. Is this something added in the newer version of grails? Because I remember that I didn't have to add it in 2.1.

Comment: It's not part of grails. It is part of the resources plugin that is now a default grails plugin.

Comment: Great. But how do I make it to be set only on development environment?

Comment: Put that in the development {} block of your Config.groovy.

Comment: When I use this, I'm getting 404s for some files that get served from `/static/`. Really weird, I turn off that flag, and everything is served fine

Comment: Of course it does. That's why you only do it in development.

Comment: How is this done int 3.1.7? I am using files in `src/main/resources/public` but changes are not loaded. I added this setting in `application.yml`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Gregg's answer doesn't work for 1.3.7 (maybe that is something added in 2.x?).  A method I found that makes quick CSS updates possible is to include a separate GSP as a template in the page header.

That is, create a file called "_css.gsp" (underscore prefix is required) in the same directory as your view files, fill it with standard css surrounded by html style tags, and then include the following in your layout header or page:

```
<g:render template="css" />
```

With that in place, the content of _css.gsp is injected into the page.  And I can make changes to _css.gsp and they are immediately reflected after page refresh without having to restart Grails.  Hope this helps someone in Grails pre-2.x!

Comment: also a note from the Grails doc about where to stick your template GSP files: "Note that if the value of the template attribute starts with a '/' it will be resolved relative to the views folder. This is useful for sharing templates between views. Without the leading '/' it will be first be resolved relative to the current controller's view folder then, failing that, the top level views folder. In either case the template file must be named with a leading underscore ('_') but referenced in the template attribute without that underscore or the '.gsp' suffix."