# Need to restart Grails after Controller super class changes

Tags: grails

I have to restart Grails after my Controller class changes. If for example I change

```
class FooController extends RestfulController<Foo>
```

into

```
class FooController //extends RestfulController<Barcode>
```

Is there a way not to restart it? (takes ages)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem so I don't think you do something wrong

Comment: See below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072535/grails-wont-load-changes-done-in-static-resources-except-when-restarting